# Dynamically detecting supported configuration/profile/JSRs in Java ME

Tags: java-me

How do I dynamically detect what profile/configuration is being used and what JSRs are supported? I know that you can [dynamically detect supported classes](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/32622/0/page/2), but I would be surprised if picking a random class that should only be in a particular profile/configuration were the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.getProperty](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr037/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) on the "microedition.configuration" and "microedition.profiles" properties. Other JSRs may have defined properties as well. Look at the list of [defined property names](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/questions/properties/index.html).