# Supporting multiple versions without separate builds in JavaME

Tags: java-me, multiple-versions

I want to be able to support multiple versions of Java ME without having to have multiple builds. I already know [how to detect the profile/configuration/supported JSRs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429429/dynamically-detecting-supported-configuration-profile-jsrs-in-java-me). My problem is that knowing whether the JSR is supported at run time doesn't allow me to use all the features as Java-ME does not provide support for reflection.

For if I call a function added in a later version anywhere in the code - even a location that will never be run, then this could cause an error during resolution on some JVMs. Is there any way round this?

**Related Questions**

- [Handling optional APIs in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591705/handling-optional-apis-in-j2me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to access the class `C` through an interface which you know you will have access to, then it is simple enough:

```
MyInterface provider=null;
try{
    Class myClass= Class.forName("sysPackage.C");
    provider = (MyInterface)(myClass.newInstance());  
}catch(Exception ex){
}
if(provide!=null){
    //Use provider
}
```

If `C` does not have an interface that can be used, then we can instead create a wrapper class `S` that will be a member of the interface instead.

```
class S implements MyInterface{
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("sysPackage.C");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    } 
    public static void forceExceptionIfUnavailable() {}
    //TODO: Methods that use C. Class C will only be used within this class
}
```

`S` has a static block so that an exception is thrown during class resolution if `C` is unavailable. Immediately after loading the class, we call `forceExceptionIfUnavailable` to make sure that the static block is run immediately. If it doesn't crash, then we can use the methods in `S` to indirectly use class `C`.

Alternatively, we can use the method [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_use_an_optional_API_in_Java_ME):

Basically, you create a new package `P`, with a public abstract class `A` and a concrete subclass `S` private to the package. `A` has a static method `getS` that returns an instance of `S` or `null` if an exception is thrown during instantiation. Each instance of `S` has an instance of `C` so it will fail to instantiate when `C` is unavailable - otherwise it will succeed. This method seems to be a bit safer as `S` (and hence all the `C` APIs) are package private.